# register two udfs with the same name on sparkSession

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-2.0

During migration form Spark 1.6 to Spark 2.2, I was faced with the problem.

Implementation on Spark 1.6 has two UDFs:

- **SparkSQL UDF** (implementation of org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF2 registered via SQLContext.udf().register(…))
- **Java custom UDFs designed for Hive** (implementation of org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDTF registered via HiveContext.sql(…))

Both UDFs were registered via one context with the same name *foo*

example in java with a Spark 1.6:

```
public static void register(SQLContext sqlContext) {
 sqlContext.udf().register("foo", new Foo(), DataTypes.StringType);
 if (sqlContext instanceof HiveContext) {
  HiveContext hiveContext = (HiveContext) sqlContext;
  hiveContext.sql(
      "create temporary function foo as 'com.FooHive'");
 }
}
```

I tried to do the same on SparkSession (Spark 2.2):

```
public static void register(SparkSession sparkSession) {
 sparkSession.udf().register("foo", new Foo(), DataTypes.StringType);
 sparkSession.sql(
      "create temporary function foo as 'com.FooHive'");
}
```

This code causes Exception:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Function foo already exists;
```

Is there way to solve this issue on SparkSession?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like this is solved for temporary function in Spark 2.3. If you see in the branch 2.2 is  using `registerFunction`

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.2/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/UDFRegistration.scala

but in 2.3 they changed it for `createOrReplaceTempFunction`

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.3/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/UDFRegistration.scala

This is just seeing the code, I hope it helps.